# How do I get the extent of a Gist index?

Tags: postgis, postgresql

I have a bunch of different tables in my database, all of them have a gist index and I want to know of two tables have data in the same area. So what is the easiest way to get the extent of the geometry?

Some tables have a column with points and some tables have a column with polygons..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use [`ST_EXTENT`](http://postgis.net/docs/ST_Extent.html) on the tables to get their bounding box, and `ST_INTERSECTS` to know if they do intersect or not. Note that it is a bounding box intersect, not a geometry intersect.

```
select st_asText(st_extent(geom)) from myLayer;


select st_intersects(a.geom,b.geom) from 
  (select st_extent(geom) geom from layer1) a,
  (select st_extent(geom) geom from layer2) b;
```

Comment: Sweet I tried with `select st_intersects(st_extent(ac.geom), st_extent(ha.geom)) from activity.talble_a ac, harvest.table_h ha` but it didn't work, your solution works nice and fast!